# Google Place Autocomplete- some of the suggestion's addresses aren't displayed in English

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete

I use Google Place Autocomplete in my app.
I import the library by

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
```

Some addresses like "Dummy Road, Zurich, Switzerland" are display in partial German (Zurich is displayed in German).

I checked also in :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

and it is also displayed this way.

Is there a way to display in English the whole address?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [language parameter](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests) which you should be able to set. By default, it'll try to load the most appropriate language based off things like browser settings. In your request add:

```
language=en
```

Comment: It affects only the State not the city and etc